# Date parameter using Entity Framework stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, datetime

I am calling a stored procedure on a SQL server DB that accepts Date parameters where `d1`, `d2` are c# `DateTime` type. I am using the entity framework to do so:

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("myprocedure @p1 @p2",dt1.Date,dt2.Date)
```

It didn't return results so I tried:

```
var p0 = new SqlParameter("p0",dt1);
p0.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Date;
var p1= new SqlParameter("p1", dt2);
p1.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Date;
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("myprocedure @p1 @p2",p0,p1)
```

Yet, if I simply do:

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("myprocedure @p1, @p2", '1/20/2014', '1/30/2014')
```

I get the correct result. Please help.. going out of my mind here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your dates also include times. To do exactly this:

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("myprocedure @p1, @p2", '1/20/2014', '1/30/2014')
```

You need to do this:

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("myprocedure @p1 @p2",dt1.Date.ToShortDateString() , dt2.Date.ToShortDateString())
```

This is because I assume your SP takes strings as opposed to DateTime types.

Note that the formatting of datestrings depends on culture. You may want to manually specify the MM/dd/YYYY format etc with the .ToString() method to ensure the SP gets the correct formatted date.

---

Also, it doesn't look like you're using entity framework correctly. There should be a method called MyProcedure on the entity framework object that you can call directly and pass the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Try Converting the `dt1` and `dt2` first, before sending the value to the parameters:

```c#
     dt1= Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/YYYY");
     dt2= Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/YYYY");
```

Comment: If you want to get the date part of a DateTime value, call the `.Date` property. Your code will actually fail because you use a localized format (US only), instead of the unambiguous `yyyy-MM-dd`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos u can change the format from MM/dd/YYYY to whatever format u need... why u make the problem more complicated?...lol

Comment: Dates don't have formats. They are binary values. Actually, it's the multiple conversions without regard to locale that make things a lot more complicated.

Comment: almost everything are binary values in computer stuff.... the date format i have mentioned can be found in this reference https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx also u said "you use a localized format (US only), instead of the unambiguous yyyy-MM-dd. –" . I feel u are abusing others with ur reputation point... not a healthy ways in share and learning environment. thank u sir

Comment: You misunderstood what I wrote. Date types have no format, just like decimals or integers don't. Hence there is no reason to use string formatting to convert them to truncate the time portion. When parsing strings to DateTime though or calling `Convert.ToDateTime` though, the current system locale is used to parse the date. Dates formatted as `yyyy-MM-dd` are unambiguous, ie they parse the same in all locales. Dates in the US  format `MM/dd/YYYY` though parses correctly only for the US locale. In every other locale you'll get either a wrong date or an Exception.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:** the Format you are providing is not what exactly DB is expecting.

**Solution :** it is always better to convert your string into `DateTime` type and send it.

Replace This:

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("myprocedure @p1, @p2", '1/20/2014', '1/30/2014')
```

With This:

```
DateTime dt1=DateTime.ParseExact("1/20/2014","M/d/yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime dt1=DateTime.ParseExact("1/30/2014","M/d/yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("myprocedure @p1, @p2", dt1,dt2);
```

Comment: The OP already tried to use DateTime values. This failed because the stored procedure accepts string parameters instead of date parameters